# Why is the 'operator' keyword optional on hasNext(), next() and iterator() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, iterator, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, iterable

I was building my own collection and when I was implementing `Iterable`, I realized that I forgot to put the `operator` keyword onto the `iterator()` method in my collection and also the two methods `hasNext()` and `next()` in my `Iterator`. The code still worked just fine, with or without the `operator` keyword. Now, I **do** understand why these methods are operator methods. I just want to know why they chose to make it an operator method and then not force the user to use the `operator` keyword next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Tenfour04's answer and my own findings, I realized that the reason why I'm not forced to use the `operator` keyword is because I'm inheriting from Kotlin's `Iterable` and `Iterator`. And these interfaces already contain the methods `iterator()`, `hasNext()` and `next()` with the keyword `operator` next to them. As the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) state:

> When overriding your operator overloads, you can omit `operator`.

And, the reason why these methods require you to use the `operator` keyword is because you are not forced to inherit from `Iterable` and `Iterator`. In Kotlin, you are welcome to create your own custom `CustomIterable` and `CustomIterator`, in which you *will* be forced to use the `operator` keyword next to the methods if you want to use the foreach loop. However, not inheriting from `Iterable` means you won't have available any of the Kotlin's useful methods for collection operations like `.forEach { … }`, `.map { … }`, `.filter { … }` etc.

Answer (score 2):

When you override a function or property, it implicitly inherits the keywords from the super type unless you use a keyword that contradicts it. The exception is `override`, which must always be explicitly used.